# Send key press inside a container

Tags: python, linux, docker, x11

I'm working on reinforcement learning AI for the game [xmoto](https://xmoto.tuxfamily.org/), in order to train fast, i need to parallelize the training with multiple agents training in same time.
The agents use pyautogui to send key to the game.

My problem:

I'm trying to use [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) inside of a docker container, i don't really know how it works (new to docker) but i get an error

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.Xauthority'

[full error stack](https://gist.github.com/louis030195/9a5cf53415989d8191508a796e00f754)

(The docker already launch xmoto at start and i can vnc it to display xmoto, the pixels are used as observations for the agent)

Any idea how to solve my problem ?

Maybe another way of sending key than pyautogui ?

[My github repository](https://github.com/louis030195/xmoto-gym)

Comment: X11 in Docker is very problematic, do you have that set up and working correctly?

Comment: yes, xmoto only without pyautogui is working with [dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/rom1504/a7ddb818a3d7a2bd41bd88209254b26b) (i run the docker, vnc into it, it shows xmoto)

Comment: And VNC is running a session for root?

Comment: If you mean that VNC opens and show Xmoto yes it does

Comment: I mean the error message indicates a problem while attempting to log in as `root`; if the VNC session doesn't belong to `root`, that's why you have a problem. In any event you should probably explain in more detail how things are set up and how exactly you are connecting. Running a graphical session for `root` is obviously dubious practice anyway, though perhaps in this scenario the risks are tolerable if it simplifies the overall process.

Comment: I'm the creator of PyAutoGUI. Running PyAutoGUI inside a container or VM hasn't really worked for others before, and it's a feature I'd like to one day add to PyAutoGUI. But for now (and the foreseeable future) this is something PyAutoGUI can't do.